# Can I still use the new Battle.net mobile authenticator if my phone does not have internet?

Tags: battle.net

The Battle.net mobile authenticator has received an update earlier this year that replaces the manual entry of a code with a single tap of a button in the app itself. However, this requires the app itself to have internet connectivity.

If my phone does not have internet connectivity when a code is requested, can I still manually enter a code generated by the app that doesn't require internet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw they added the accept/deny feature recently but it didn't always work for me. I've been having WiFi issues myself so every once in a while my authenticator doesn't prompt me. When I launch the authenticator, there's a button at the bottom that says "enter code manually." press that and it makes a code.  I also just turned my phone to airplane mode, launched the authenticator, and got a code.

Comment: Keep in mind that the codes are time-based, so the device's clock must be relatively correct.